# Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++

I have a problem in my string class. After `cin.get` compiler display me this expression. Where did I go wrong?

```
//Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "str.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
        str S1 = "Hello, world!";
        str S2 = "LOL";
        str S3 = S2;
        cout << S3.cstr() << endl;
        cout << S1.size() << ": " << S1.cstr() << endl;
        cin.get();
}



//str.h
#ifndef STR_H
#define STR_H

class str
{
public:
        str(const char* = "");
        ~str();
        void operator=(const char*);
        void operator=(str);
        const char* cstr();
        int size();
private:
        void newString(const char*);
        char* charPtr;
        int Size;
};

#endif




//str.cpp
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <cstring>
    using std::strlen;
    using std::strcpy;

    #include "str.h"

    str::str(const char* cstr)
    {
        newString(cstr);
    }
    str::~str()
    {
        delete[] charPtr;
    }
    const char* str::cstr()
    {
        return charPtr;
    }
    void str::newString(const char* cstr)
    {
        delete[] charPtr;
        Size = strlen(cstr);
        charPtr = new char[Size + 1];
        strcpy(charPtr, cstr);
    }
    void str::operator=(const char* cstr)
    {
        newString(cstr);
    }
    int str::size()
    {
        return Size;
    }
```

Comment: @RakibulHasan Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Comment: Please post relevant code here, not via links.

Comment: You really shouldn't use identifiers begining with an underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't obey the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). You have user defined destructor and copy assignment operator, but you haven't defined a copy constructor. The compiler helpfully`</sarcasm>` defined one for you.

On this line:

```
str S3 = S2;
```

You [copy initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) S3. As you can see from the rules in the linked page:

> If T is a class type and the type of other is cv-unqualified version of T or a class derived from T, the constructors of T are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

The best matching constructor happens to be the `str(const str&);` which was added by the compier. The default copy constructor does not make a copy of the data pointed by the charPtr but just copies the pointer instead.

When S2 goes out of scope, after `cin.get();`, it's destructor deletes S2.charPtr. Next, S3 is destroyed and it's destructor tries to delete S3.charPtr which has the same value as S2.charPtr and is therefore already deleted. [This has undefined behaviour](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/double-delete-disaster.html). [Quick googling](https://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/457488) suggests that `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID` assertion fails if heap pointer is invalid. I'm guessing it's likely result of this undefined behaviour.

Solution: Implement the copy constructor `str(const str&);` so that copies don't share data.